# Apache Webserver does not show directory listings but 403 - Yosemite

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, osx-yosemite

localhost points to /Libary/WebServer/Documents. If I have an index.html file in there it opens, no problems. However if I remove the index file it gives me a 403 error instead of showing the directory listing - same applies for all subfolders.

Just upgraded to Yosemite, MBA.

How can I get it to show directory listings again?

-Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open "/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf" in an editor.  Scroll down until you find this part:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

Inside there you'll need to add "Indexes" to your "Options".  For me, this meant changing this line:

```
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
```

To:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
```

Then restart apache:

```
apachectl restart
```

Comment: Hot to get permission for textEditor to modify file?

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! it worked for me.

*Why "Indexes"* ?

**Indexes**
    If a URL which maps to a directory is requested, and there is no DirectoryIndex (e.g., index.html) in that directory, then mod_autoindex will return a formatted listing of the directory.

Ref - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options